# Ruby on Rails - delegate devise member on has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between `keywords` and `groups` and then a  `groups` `belongs_to` `member` association  between group and devise.

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  delegate :member, to: :groups
  validate :keywords_within_limit, on: :create

  def keywords_within_limit
    if self.member.keywords(:reload).count >= self.member.keyword_limit
       errors.add(:keyword, "exceeded limit")
    end
  end
end
```

Im trying access my current members methods using `delegate` but I am getting the error `NoMethodError - undefined method member for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>:`

I can see member is a method by doing `self.methods`

Why can't I access my members methods using `delegate`?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see there is a many to many mapping between keyword and group. So the groups method would return a collection of groups and not a single record for group. So when you delegate 'member', it is delegated to a collection of groups rather than a group object as you are expecting.

The `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []`> in your error message
is the groups collection.

If you are looking to collect members of all the groups you may need to do something like:

```
def members
  groups.collect { |group| group.member }
end
```

Comment: I am trying to get the number of keywords the current member has when they are adding a new keyword.

Comment: any idea how i can do that??

Comment: Since group belongs_to member, maybe member has_many groups? So maybe ` member.groups.collect { |group| group.keywords }.uniq` may work.